# how to update a column in a table by joining another table with only certain rows getting updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2014

I have two tables, A and B

```
 Table A

ID     | value                          
------ | ------                
1      |  20                 
2      |  21               
3      |  25

Table B

ID     | value         
------ | ------
1      |  15
2      |  10
```

And I need to update the value column of table A, with the corresponding values of table B. The issue is Table A gets updated every day and, when ever it gets updated- it updates with the same old values, so I need to create a query so that it can be used as a package for scheduling it to run everyday with the correct values. 
Also, some of the IDs and its corresponding values which are not present in Table B, should not be altered. Can someone help me with this.
I am using sql server 2014

This is the Query that I am using.

`SELECT A.[SUBSTAT_NAME]
      ,A.[FDR_NUM]
      ,A.[XFMR_ID]
      ,A.[XFMR_SIZE]
      ,B.DRG_size
      ,A.[PAD_R]
      ,A.[CONDUCT_ID]
      ,A.[PHASE]
      ,A.[SRV_LOC_NUM]
      ,A.[BUS]
     ,A.DATE_TIME
  FROM [SERV_LOC_XFMR_GIS_PROD] A left join
  [XFMR_LESS_THAN_10] B 
  on A.XFMR_ID = B.XFMR_ID`

So I need the DRG_SIZE value to be replaced with XFMR_SIZE, when the XFMR_ID match. But the rest of the IDs in Table A should not be altered and should be displayed in the results

Comment: Sure we can help. The query for this should be pretty simple. However you haven't provided us with any real details. If you can post some ddl and sample data we can easily help. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ Without those details we are just guessing as to what you want.

Comment: sounds like a perfect opportunity to learn about MERGE https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: Why update?  Why not just create a view that joins the tables together so you always get the latest value?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  maybe table b gets wiped daily?  good question though

Comment: Hello friends, my issue is, My table A has  500 IDs with their corresponding values, My table B has 100 IDs with their corresponding values. These 100 IDs of table B are also present in table A, but with a different value. So I need to update table A, but with only the IDs which are present in table B. The other 400 ID's values should not be altered.
I do not want to use update statement, I need a select query which cam update table A. And I want to run it in a package

Comment: You should simply write a sql server stored procedure with one of the solutions provided in the answers below. They are all good for your need.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the following general syntax:

```
update a
set a.c1 = b.c1
from tableA as a
inner join tableB as b on b.c2 = a.c2
```

First test that with

```
select a.c1, a.c2, b.c1, b.c2
from tableA as a
inner join tableB as b on b.c2 = a.c2
```

and see if your join produces the correct results. Then write an `update` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, but make sure to save a backup first:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.value = B.value
FROM A, B
WHERE A.id = B.id
```